# Find ASCII equivalent of each & every number & add them using python

Tags: python

I've a number like this.

```
num=99856

ASCII 9= 57
ASCII 9= 57
ASCII 8= 56
ASCII 5= 53
ASCII 6= 54
```

I want to add all the equivalents.
Like

```
57+57+56+53+54 = 277
```

Currently I've worked up to finding ASCII equivalent of each number.

```
for char in "99856":
    print(f"{char} {ord(char)}", end="\t")
```

output

```
9 57    9 57    8 56    5 53    6 54
```

Next part is to add them. Can anyone suggest what would be the next execution steps. Like should I convert output to list? & thereby adding elements in list?. If you guys know any simple process pls suggest me

Comment: `sum(map(ord, str(num)))` or `sum(map(ord, num))` if `num` is already a string. You can also pass [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map): `sum(ord(d) for d in num)`

Comment: It's really not clear what's unclear. Add them?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to add them in the loop:

```py
total = 0
for char in "99856":
    code = ord(char)
    print(f"{char} {code}", end="\n")
    total += code
print('Sum: ', total)
```